# Counting symbols in multiple variables

Tags: stata

I would like to count how many plus and minus signs, as well as asterisks
and question marks there are for each row for all variables.

For example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1(var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10)
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "+" "-" "+"
"+" "-" "-" "-" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "?"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "-" "-" "-"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "*" "*" "*" "*" "*"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "-" "-" "*" "*" "*"
"+" "*" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"
"-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "+" "+" "+" "+"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
end
```

How can I count these given that my variables are all strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this purely from string manipulations. If we concatenate all to a single string, we can count any character we please by the following device: pretend to replace each instance of that character by nothing (so, pretend to remove it) and then see how much shorter the string is. This trick was written up [in this 2011 paper accessible to all](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0056).

Counting asterisks is just another example.

The concatenated combination has other uses, especially if the variables refer to a sequence or history of some kind.

I here repeat the code to create your data example for the convenience of anyone wishing to play with the code.

```
clear
input str1(var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10)
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "+" "-" "+"
"+" "-" "-" "-" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "?"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "-" "-" "-"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "*" "*" "*" "*" "*"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "-" "-" "*" "*" "*"
"+" "*" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"
"-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "+" "+" "+" "+"
"+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
end

egen all = concat(var*) 

gen plus = 10 - length(subinstr(all, "+", "", .)) 
gen minus = 10 - length(subinstr(all, "-", "", .)) 
gen question = 10 - length(subinstr(all, "?", "", .)) 

list all plus minus question, sep(0) 

     +--------------------------------------+
     |        all   plus   minus   question |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. | ++++++++++     10       0          0 |
  2. | ++++++-+-+      8       2          0 |
  3. | +---+++++?      6       3          1 |
  4. | ++++++----      6       4          0 |
  5. | +++++*****      5       0          0 |
  6. | ++++---***      4       3          0 |
  7. | +*++++++++      9       0          0 |
  8. | ++++------      4       6          0 |
  9. | ------++++      4       6          0 |
 10. | ++++++++++     10       0          0 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Very nice (+1). I had forgotten about the `concat()` function.

Comment: Thanks! That was written by me in or before 1999 ... it was probably just implementing ideas floating around at the time.